# Declare and change global variable in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, .net-core

I develop an Angular app based on .NET Core and I want to create a global variable for countries by using a `DropdownList` so that the global value can be changed easily. Then access this global value (selected country) through all of the other pages. Normally I would use the following approach, but I have really no idea how should I modify the following approach so that the user can set the global filter value (selected country) at any time.

***globals.ts:***

```
export const version: string="22.2.2";
```

***heroes.component.ts:***

```
import * as myGlobals from 'globals';

export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
public heroes: Hero[];
public selectedHero: Hero;

// Here we access the global var reference
public helloString: string="hello " + myGlobals.version + " there";

     ...

    }
}
```

However, I have no idea how can I set this global value by using this approach or is there any approach for this. Is there any proper way for this?

Shall I add a dropdownlist to `globals.ts` and update the `version` whenever user select the version on this dropdownlist?

**Is using a service with** `BehaviourSubject` **the best option for fixing this issue?**

Comment: You can use service variable approach for global variables

Comment: You should use a service.

Comment: Thanks for replies. Actually I thought to use service, but actually avoided a little bit. Is there any solution to use a variable ash shown on the approach above? Yes it could not be a constant as it is changed. But I just want to be sure if there is a proper approach for this scenario.

Comment: If the service is the only option, I think I should use `BehaviourSubject` as I have used several times in my project.

Comment: @zainhassan Any reply please?

Comment: @Beller Any reply please?

Comment: @Natalia The proper approach is to use service and it is good to use BehaviourSubject as it has initial value and any change in subject can be listened

Comment: Thanks, I think there is no choice for this scenario except from using `service` or `localStorage`. Is that true? I just wanted to be sure before starting.

Comment: Yes. localStorage is better if you want to persist value like language selection. Otherwise service

Comment: The problem with `localStorage` is that it is a little bit risky when it is not deleted when needed. But if I have another option, I would generally avoid from using it. In this case service with BehaviourSubject is the best option I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html5 storage its allow up to 5mb

set value : localStorage.setItem(keyname, value)

get value : localStorage.getValue(keyname, value)

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_setitem.asp

Comment: Thanks, we also thought that, but **we do not want to use** `localStorage`

Comment: @Beller Any other suggestion except from `localStorage`?

Comment: @Natalia NgRx store?